# MySQL Left Join behaving like Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, right-join

Here is my query:

```
SELECT logins.user as user, 
       rozliczenia.godziny as godziny, 
       rozliczenia.stawka  as stawka, 
       rozliczenia.premia as premia, 
       rozliczenia.premiainna as premiainna 
  FROM logins 
       LEFT JOIN rozliczenia ON logins.id=rozliczenia.userid 
 WHERE user!='SUPERUSER' 
   AND user!='agata' 
   AND user!='tomek' 
   AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN 
          DATE('$rok-$mies-00') AND DATE('$rok-$mies-$daysinm')
```

In my logins there are:

```
bartosz
iza
grzegorz
slawek
pawel
michal
```

but in my rozliczenia table i have only:

```
bartosz
iza
grzegorz
slawek
pawel
```

Left join should return all users from logins table, but it works like an inner join?

Comment: Most probably your where conditions is doing that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `where` clause is turning the outer join into an inner join.  At least this clause does:

```
 DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00') AND DATE('$rok-$mies-$daysinm')
```

When there is no match, then this fails, because `data` is `NULL`.

You need to move any conditions on the *second* table to the `on` clause.  I'm not sure if this is the only such condition.

Answer (score 2):

This turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER one

```
WHERE ... AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN ...
```

Since results with no "right" will have NULL for all fields, `DATE(rozliczenia.data)` will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT logins.user as user, 
       rozliczenia.godziny as godziny, 
       rozliczenia.stawka as stawka, 
       rozliczenia.premia as premia, 
       rozliczenia.premiainna as premiainna 
FROM logins LEFT JOIN rozliczenia 
ON (logins.id=rozliczenia.userid) and
   DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00') AND DATE('$rok-$mies-$daysinm')
WHERE user!='SUPERUSER' AND user!='agata' AND user!='tomek'
```